# Animate listview from back of layout

Tags: android, animation

I am working on animation, I have one Layout and list-view and I am applying animation to list-view from left to right, **Its working fine but list-view slide front of layout and I want to do from back of layout**.

On click of layout list-view will slide from left to right and it hold the place beside layout like below images.

[image: When I click layout it will slide my list-view see the next image]

[image: It will slide and hold beside layout but slide from front of layout and I want from back of layout]

Thanks.

Comment: a lil workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392179/how-to-bring-a-view-to-front-without-calling-bringtofront

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Understand the View order(Hierarchy)
let me make it clear with an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
> 

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tvMessage" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="dasdjfiuihuhds" /> 
<Button 
android:id="@+id/btnOk" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Ok" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**This will make Textview over ButtonView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
> 
<Button 
android:id="@+id/btnOk" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Ok" /> 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tvMessage" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="dasdjfiuihuhds" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**This will make Button over TextView**

1st case code

```
<RelativeLayout > 
<TextView> 
<Button>
```

2nd case code

```
<RelativeLayout > 
<Button> 
<TextView>
```

*in Short you can maintain order by following code hierarchy*