# Overlap an imageview on top of another imageview to make animation

Tags: android, xml, animation, core-animation, android-animation

I'm developing an android application. I want to create animation with `imageviews`. Currently, I have 20-25 images to make some actions with those images.

I want to overlap one image on top of another image without any user interaction.

So please help me asap.

Hey, I tried this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

With this, my application crashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow the hierarchy of writing code(xml) in such manner that the back order imageview will written first and then so on, see [Animate listview from back of layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616384/animate-listview-from-back-of-layout/8623988#8623988)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good idea to use an AnimationDrawable if you would like to make animation:
[AnimationDrawable Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)