# how to arrange views in a layout through an activity

Tags: java, android, layout, android-activity

I made an activity in java that creates a relative layout and 2 views, and I want to arrange them one below the other in the middle of the screen, but I can't find any of the xml orders in java at android.com.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can arrange(front or back) layout views through layout xml itself see this link [Animate listview from back of layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616384/animate-listview-from-back-of-layout/8623988#8623988)

Comment: I know but I want to arrange them through the Activity, not an xml file

Comment: samething can be done in Activity too, view.addview(bottom), view.addview(middle), view.addview(top). In short newly added view is at the top

Comment: when I use add view they go one above the other, how do I tell the second one to align below the first?

Comment: Use Relative layout, or can use linearlayout by setting orientation property to VERTICAL

Comment: i am using relative, and i'm adding them one after an other via addView, i'm adding them to the layout with addView

Comment: see concept of layoutparams you will get you know how to align

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically