# Button below the sliding drawer is registering the click

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, slidingdrawer

I have a linearlayout at the bottom of the screen. its width fills the screen and that layout has a button which fills the layout.. above that layout have a sliding drawer in the middle of the screen which is half the linearlayout width.I have Programatically made sliding drawer to come to front by calling it with bringtofront() method. Problem i m facing is the button inside the linearlayout takes the click in the space between the content items. I need it to take the click only outside the sliding drawer but not inside the content of the sliding drawer,, can anyone help me out please.. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a *boolean* which holds slider status(open/close)

```
if(open)
//Disable button's click 
else
//Enable button's click
```

Comment: No that is not possible.. i need it to be clickable elsewhere other then sliding drawer part

Comment: then problem will be there if you taking Slider programmatically, cant you take it in xml?

Comment: did the slider in xml only made it to come to front programmatically so that it takes clicks to the content gets registered properly.

Comment: yes, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616384/animate-listview-from-back-of-layout