# Image animation not overlapping in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a layout like

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/slide_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_homeslide_1"/>

<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             ..
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                .../>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to animate the ImageView above. Its transition is from bottom to up . But the problem is when the imageview animate, the footer layout is overlapping the image. I need the image view to animate above all views. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the hierarchy of writing code(xml) in such manner that the back order imageview will written first and then so on, see

[Animate listview from back of layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616384/animate-listview-from-back-of-layout/8623988#8623988)

Comment: It did not work because I am starting the animations only after all the view are drawn