# fill parent on a textview doesn't apply

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, fill-parent

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I have looked on all the solution I could see and none of them worked.
I have a textview inside a relative-layout. the textview has a height : fill_parent atribute that does not work. the pun is that they are severall other textview in this relative-layoutwhich all manage to fill parent,except for this one.
here is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistdescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mainlistquantite"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
         />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistquantite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/consultaffichelayoutdroit"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
         />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/consultafficheseparator" <!-- the one not working-->
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:maxWidth="2dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:src="@drawable/fleche" /> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/consultaffichelayoutdroit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/consultafficheseparator"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
         >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainlistnumero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainlistprix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is what i get : [image]

the grey bar should go all the way but doesn't when actually running on the emulator( it does in the eclipse tool)

since this xml is actually called in a list view, I can't seem to fix the problem using JAVA code, so the solution would ideally be on the XML file. I tryed so far android:clipChildren="false" without sucess, as well as changing the order of my elements in the XML, wich juste made it worse.

after experiment,I can tell nothing takes the place so it's not the it cannot go because there is allready a view there,it just doesn't expand that far

thanks for the help on that

Comment: android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mainlistquantite" why?

Comment: indeed,it's useless,i'll take it out,and thanks for the edit!
EDIT : after removing it,it wasn't useless : it keep the text from going over everything... but it does look bad on the code,I agree with you on that

Comment: can u please share the screenshot displaying ur problem

Comment: if you doesn't show your required UI how can we say what is problem?

Comment: @wazaminator your above code working well and line extend fill whole page

Comment: it does seem to grow well in eclipse,but actually doesn't on the emulator

Comment: Have you tried on a real android device? It might be an emulator-issue.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a TextView to draw a separator? Try with a normal view like the code below.

Also, if the seperator has to align to the bottom of your description view, you can use the `layout_alignBottom`-property of `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainlistdescription"
```

So the separator would look something like the code below:

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/consultafficheseparator"
     android:layout_width="2dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainlistdescription"
     android:background="@color/separator_bg" />
```

---

Below some other tips:

1. It's better to define a color in some resource-file (eg. `colors.xml`) and refer to that color from inside your layout. Especially when using it in a `ListView`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <color name="separator_bg">#777777</color>
   </resources>
   ```

   And in your layout-file `android:background="@color/separator_bg"`
2. Use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` because that's deprecated.
3. I see `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` on one of the `TextView`'s. That only works when the `TextView` is editable. If you want the content to scroll because it doesn't fit in the `TextView`, try to use the code below:

   ```
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   ```

   And in your `adapter.getView()`:

   ```
   final TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainlistdescription);
   description.setSelected(true);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your TextView is not at the top level, maybe you can try the following in your code:

```
consultafficheseparatorTextView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: my problem is,this whole xml is included in a listview and repeted a lot of time. this makes it verry difficult to acces through the JAVA code. if you know a solution thourgh the XML code,I will be glad

Comment: According to the question below, you can maybe try this: `android:clipChildren="false"`.
Here is where I got this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392179/how-to-bring-a-view-to-front-without-calling-bringtofront

Answer (score 0):

Had the same pesky problem which by the way makes no sense. What worked for me in the end was changing the `android:layout_height` in RelativeLayout tag to `fill_parent` like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try setting one (or all) of the following to see if it changes anything:

```
android:maxHeight="100dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

or

```
android:text="a"
android:textColor="#777777"
```

If any of these options change the size, please let me know and we can work on a proper solution!

Comment: the photo is actually zoomed a lot,so I changed the 100dp to see : 

first one made it become smaller(had to use 10dp instead of 100).

second one made it to 100dp,expending as you would think it would. 

I allready tried the third one,it did not work

Comment: Wait, you lost me! What photo?

Comment: the image of the problem,sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange you get such view of this layout, because after copy&paste of your layout code I've got this one.

Your solution works, I've made some minor improvments. It's like your code, but there is no need to use TextView if you need background color only, View could be used instead.

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/consultafficheseparator"
     android:layout_width="2dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:background="#777777"
/>
```

Only suggestion is to set root layout height "match_parent" or some value in dp, like **thiagolr** proposed. I've set it to "100dp" for this screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: well,another problem is,the size of it all depens a lot of what's inside mainlistdescription,you can go from 1 to 4 lines easily

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/customshape"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainlistdescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mainlistquantite"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainlistquantite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/consultaffichelayoutdroit"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:src="@drawable/fleche" /> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/consultafficheseparator" <!-- this will work now -->
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:background="#777777"
    android:maxWidth="2dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/consultaffichelayoutdroit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/consultafficheseparator"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistnumero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistprix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can  you explain what did you change please? so that I can understund where did I do wrong please?

Comment: can you explain the differences please? After a try, it did Not work, sorry

Answer (score 0):

1)Try to make your Linear Layout orientation vertical
or
2)Try to make your Relative Layout orientation vertical

it can be help.